# What would unhook my View and Controller from each other in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have previously successfully tested this MVC functionality in my app in Chrome but have recenlty also tested in IE (10) and Firefox.

When I mash the submit button on a page which sends model values to its controller for running a query and generating a report, it now works only in Firefox (each of the three browser indeed have their own peculiar characteristics -- where they shine or "dull" in relation to their cohorts (gleaming in purple and gold) -- but Chrome and Firefox seem to have lost the connection between the submit button's click handler and the corresponding Controller's method.

The app seems to simply hang after mashing the submit button in Chrome and IE; the breakpoints I have -- the first of which is at the very beginning of the corresponding [HttpPost] ActionResult in the Controller class -- are not reached. In fact, the app seems to freeze after mashing the button -- right-clicking the submit button after that does not give me an "inspect that element" in the context menu.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria(SalesReceiptCriteriaModel model) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // <-- there is a breakpoint here; only Firefox reaches it
        {
            . . .
```

In Firefox, it runs, and the breakpoints are hit.

What could possibly cause Chrome and IE to fail in this way, wheras Firefox soldiers on?

### UPDATE

In response to Moby's request, here is the jQuery for the View in question:

The HTML in the View is pretty generic; the jQuery is:

```
        $("#submit_button").click(function() {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192288/how-can-i-compare-date-time-values-using-the-jqueryui-datepicker-and-html5-time
            var begD = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $('#BeginDate').val());
            var endD = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $('#EndDate').val());
            if (begD > endD) {
                alert('Begin date must be before End date');
                $('#BeginDate').focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if (begD.toString() == endD.toString()) {
                var dteString = begD.getFullYear() + "/" + (begD.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + begD.getDate();
                var begT = new Date(dteString + " " + $('#BeginTime').val());
                var endT = new Date(dteString + " " + $('#EndTime').val());

                if (begT > endT) {
                    alert('Begin date must be before End date');
                    $('#BeginTime').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $("#NumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#NumberOfResults").html("Please wait...");

            EnableButton("submit_button", false);

            // If all are selected, don't enumerate them; just set it at "All" (change of case, from 'all' to 'All', shows that the logic did execute)
            var deptsList = $('#depts').checkedBoxes();
            if (deptsList.length < deptsArray.length) {
                $('#deptHeader span').html(deptsList.join(", "));
            }
            else if (deptsList.length == deptsArray.length) {
                $('#deptHeader span').html("All");
            }
            // " "
            var sitesList = $('#sites').checkedBoxes();
            $('#sitesHeader span').html(sitesList.join(", "));
            if (sitesList.length < sitesArray.length) {
                $('#sitesHeader span').html(sitesList.join(", "));
            }
            else if (sitesList.length == sitesArray.length) {
                $('#sitesHeader span').html("All");
            }

            $('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList);
            $('#hiddenSites').val(sitesList);
            var UPCs = $('#UPC').val();
            if (UPCs == "All") {
                $('#UPC').val("1"); // take everything (1 and greater)
            }

            var resultsText = jQuery.trim($("#spanNumberOfResults").text());
            if (resultsText != "") {
                $("#NumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");

                if (resultsText == "0") {
                    $("#NumberOfResults").css("color", "red");
                } else {
                    var href = '/@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/TLDCriteria/LoadReport';
                    var report_parms = {
                        GUID: "@Model.GUID",
                        SerialNumber: "@Model.SerialNumber",
                        ReportName: "@Model.ReportName"
                    };
                    window.open(href, "report_window", "resizable=1, width=850, left=" + (screen.width / 2 - 425));
                }
            }
        }); // end of submit button click

function EnableButton(id, enable) {
    if (enable) {
        $("#" + id).removeAttr("disabled")
            .removeClass("bottomButtonDisabled")
            .removeClass("bottomButtonEnabled")
            .addClass("bottomButtonEnabled");
    } else {
        $("#" + id).attr("disabled", "true")
            .removeClass("bottomButtonDisabled")
            .removeClass("bottomButtonEnabled")
            .addClass("bottomButtonDisabled");
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Something else which may or may not shed some light on this problem is my .js and .css references:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer > </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript" defer> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript" defer> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/anytime.compressed.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dynamicCheckboxes.js")" type="text/javascript" > </script>
```

. . .

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dynamicCheckboxes.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/anytime.compressed.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/Scripts/html5shiv.js"> </script>
<![endif]-->
```

### UPDATE 3

The Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools looks like the middle of Wyoming (a whole lot of nothing), with a msg about the bottom informing me "*No requests captured. Reload the page to see detailed information on the network activity.*"

When I dutifully mashed F5, it showed all the .js and .css files accessed, and finally (at the top), the page I'm gawking at. Mashing the "View Report" causes no more activity in the tab, though. I do see the console.log() msg I placed at the end of the submit button click handler, though, to wit: "*made it to the end of submit button click*"

There *is* one err msg in the console, too, but this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://localhost/%3C%=%20System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[%22ThisApp%22]%20%%3E/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png
```

Would simply fail to load the resource, not wreak other mayhem, right?

### UPDATE 4

Based on Simon Halsey's hint, I found that, on stepping though the jQuery in Chrome, it fails this test:

```
if (resultsText != "") {
```

...obviously it's not in Firefox, and I assume that it also fails in IE (I'll czech to be sure in both cases, and update this).

Later: It's "" in Firefox, too...and the *first* time through, it also failed-wouldn't continue on. Second time through, it got through, though...???

Comment: Could you add a few details to the question please, Clay? Like what your view looks like (full page post or AJAX post?), whether there are any console errors occurring in each of the browsers, and finally what kind of client side script do you have going on? Not being able to inspect an element, suggests a script attached to the submit, disabling the submit input to prevent double posts - which could be erroring. I'd like to help you, but I need more to go on. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Moby; Monday I can post some of those details. BTW: Dick or Grape?

Comment: This does sound more like a UI issue than a server issue, given that FF is still working

Comment: It smells of a jQuery issue.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble: I don't know what you mean by the view - do you want to see the HTML and jQuery in the cshtml file? As to script attached to the submit, there definitely is: the majority of the jQuery is in response to the submit button being clicked. And yes, there is code to disable the button. I consider this to be a good thing - to prevent double posts, as you mentioned - but why would it behave differently between browsers?

Comment: In chrome does the network tab show a request being submitted to the server? if yes, what happens if you try to open that URL in another tab?

Comment: Have you used the the browser debugger to step through the javascript to see where it fails? Also, you declared report_parms, but don't use it. is this important?

Comment: @SimonHalsey: I at first thought that report_parms was useless (dead code), but then, on closer inspection of the code, I see that it is referenced by the code that opens a new (Silverlight) window.

Comment: @JTMon: Update 3 details the results of your suggestion.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: Czech Update 4, please

Comment: You should post the html markup for the DOM subtree containing #NumberOfResults and #spanNumberOfResults as well as any js code that modify their content, and explain how they are populated

Comment: Actually, I think #spanNumberOfResults was a mistake that somehow creeped in; once I removed the "span", the label with the ID "NumberOfResults" does now have a non-empty-string value and so the condition succeeds. Still it is a conundrum why Firefox proceeded with the Submit process whereas Chrome and IE threw up their hands either in desperation or in the "Here and no further!" gesture.

Comment: Can you show us the form tag that gets rendered on the page via source view?  As a side note, you should consider using bundling for your javascript and css.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: Here's the form as rendered:
<form action="/TLDReporter/TLDCriteria/ReceiptCriteria" method="post"> 

This makes me wonder if the action is wrong; it looks wrong; it looks as if it's posting back to itself (ReceiptCriteria.cshtml). It should be posting, I would think, to the controller (TLDCriteriaController.cs), and the HttpPost ActionResult method there *does* get called, so...I'm corn-fuzed.

Comment: It's posting back to the ReceiptCriteria action in the TLDCriteriaController (or should be).  I'm not sure what TLDReporter is though.  Likely your sitename.

Comment: This code looks odd because it appears to be wanting to both submit the form on the page and also open a new window.  You are also creating a report_params object, yet never using it.

Comment: TLDReporter is the name of the project (one of many in a gigantic solution)

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of odd/weird: after the user enters parameters, a Silverlight window is invoked with the report contained within it. Unfortunately, I can't write "Silverlight" without hearing Bing Crosby sing about it in my mind's ear ("Silverlight...Silverlight...it's catnip time for the kitty..."). The "report_parms" (sic) is actually referenced elsewhere. At least, an attempt is made to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two options:

- There is no request due to javascript error
- Your request signature doesnt math controller method

A.
Browsers have different behaivior with some javascript functions. Thats one of the reasons why jQuery is so popular.

The most efficient way to find it is to debug javascript line by line in each browser.

Likely it is the reason.

B.
Also your javascript is quite exotic for me. I guess you are catching sumbit button click and modifying inputs values on a fly.

I would recommend to use $.post or $.ajax and preventDefault instead.
It would make your javascript more clear and simple.

C.
To analyze what requests are sent from your browser I would recommend to use fiddler. 
http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Thanks, [your name with Roman characters]; AFAIK, all my code is jQuery - no "raw" Javascript. Those are some good things to consider that you mention; I was aware of fiddler, but will now czech it out more carefully.

Comment: There *is* a request, as "if (ModelState.IsValid)" in the Controller's httpPost ActionResult is reached, and passes the test (IsValid == true); not sure what you mean about the request signature not maping to the controller method, though -- do you mean that *all* model members must be assigned valid values, or...???

Comment: Clay, in your question you told that ie and chrome doesnt hit break point in the very begining of your method. This could be only in two cases there was no request or request signature didnt meet method signature or any other filter.
If you are sure that there is request and you can check it with filddler(also i would recommend to compare them). You can put break point into OnActionExecuting method in your base controller. OnActionExecuting ll be hit almost always even if there is some errors.
I checked if your way of modifing post on a fly could be the reason but it is not.

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. I'll czech out OnActionExecuting()...OnActionExecuting does not appear anywhere in the project, nor even in the entire solution.

Comment: It seems all the F12 tools (Chrom Dev Tools, Firebug, IE's tools) all let you inspect the Requests. I have none, though, due to, apparently, the missing values in report_parms (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365504/does-the-controllers-httppost-actionresult-get-called-at-the-start-of-during)

Comment: OnActionExecuting is method of Cotroller class witch is base of any controller in your project. It can be overloaded to do some nasty things. And you can put break point into it and look why actually your method was not hit.
[Controller class description in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Yeah, to inpect request in browser dev tools helps in most common situations. But when you have strange behavior in different browsers it is more easy to research all requests in one tool also there are just a little more details about reqeust =)

Comment: This is still not really resolved, but I resolved to award the bounty to Pavel, because he had some good pointers/suggestions/hints/nudges.