# Why does Resharper say, "Not all code paths return a value" in a jQuery ready handler?

Tags: jquery, resharper

Why does Resharper say, "Not all code paths return a value" on this line of jQuery at the end of a ready handler:

```
}); // end of submit button click
```

? R# offers to add this above that line:

```
return false;
```

Why is prepending that to "});" preferred?/desired?

Comment: My guess is Resharper sees that as a problem, though it isn't a problem as jquery doesn't expect you to return anything there. Faulty behavior of Resharper imo, not every function is supposed to return something.

Comment: Unfortunately R# isn't yet quite as good at Javascript as it is at C# and VB.NET.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256969/why-does-r-tell-me-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-in-a-click-handler ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that; if it weren't for a bad memory, I'd have no memory at all - and that was only a month ago!